# latest version jQuery Mobile broke my custom themes

Tags: jquery-mobile, themes

When I use the latest version of jQuery Mobile (referencing http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js in my index.html page), my custom jQuery Mobile theme no longer works.  I created a custom theme named with a swatch named "g".  When I load my site, my header changes from ui-bar-g to ui-bar-a.  What could be causing my custom themes to be replaced with a different swatch?  Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out.  In my previous version of jQuery Mobile(), it appears a header would assume it's parent's (aka the page) data-theme.  When I switched over to latest, that assumption is no longer valid.  I have to specify the data-theme for the header.  It no longer is inheriting it's parent's data-theme.